# Django: ManyToMany widget won't be displayed as double list

Tags: django, filter, django-admin, widget, many-to-many

Hi Stackoverflow people,

I would like to change the m2m widget in the admin pages (and later in the actual django site) to a more user friendly double list (like this [one](http://blog.micayael.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/doublelist.png)).

I understand that [django.contrib.admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006401/django-custom-widget-for-manytomany-field) could do this for me. However, I have trouble to get it to work. I have added the code below to my admin.py, but the widget is not changing when I view the model in the admin app.

I have tried to adopt the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660260/django-admin-form-for-many-to-many-relationship). Every SupplierProfile should connect to one or more countries from the WorldBorder model (based on the [GeoDjango example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#worldborders))

**Where is the flaw in the code? I can't see why it would not be displayed. 
Thank you for your help!**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from apps.profile.models import (UserProfile,
                                  SupplierProfile)
from apps.gis_data.models import WorldBorder


class WorldBorderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizonal = ('name',)

class SupplierProfileAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    distribution_location_country = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset = WorldBorder.objects.all(), 
            required = False,
            widget = FilteredSelectMultiple(
            verbose_name = _('Distribution Country'),
            is_stacked=False
        )
     )

    class Meta:
        model = SupplierProfile

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SupplierProfileAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.instance:
          self.fields['distribution_location_country'].initial = self.instance.distribution_location_country.all()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        profile = super(SupplierProfileAdminForm, self).save(commit=False)

        profile.distribution_location_country = self.cleaned_data['distribution_location_country']

        if commit:
            profile.save()
            profile.save_m2m()

        return profile

class SupplierProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = SupplierProfileAdminForm

admin.site.register(SupplierProfile, admin.OSMGeoAdmin)
```

**Updated code of admin.py**

Is it possible to define the double list as stated below? "distribution_location_country" is the m2m field in my SupplierProfile. For some reason, it is still not coming through.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple
from django.contrib.gis import admin

class SupplierProfileAdmin(admin.OSMGeoAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('distribution_location_country', )

admin.site.register(SupplierProfile, SupplierProfileAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `register` line seems to be wrong:

```
admin.site.register(SupplierProfile, admin.OSMGeoAdmin)
```

doesn't register your customized `SupplierProfileAdmin` with your model.

Perhaps you want the base class of `SupplierProfileAdmin` to be `OSMGeoAdmin` instead of `ModelAdmin`:

```
class SupplierProfileAdmin(admin.OSMGeoAdmin):
    form = SupplierProfileAdminForm
```

and your register line to be

```
admin.site.register(SupplierProfile, SupplierProfileAdmin)
```

Also, I'm not sure about this, but you might just be able to use

```
filter_horizonal = ('name_of_the_m2m_field_on_the_model', )
```

on your `SupplierProfileModel` instead of that custom field on the form?

Comment: Hi agf, what is the correct registration? -> admin.site.register(SupplierProfile, admin.SupplierProfileAdmin) or -> admin.site.register(SupplierProfile, SupplierProfileAdmin)? If I go with the first one, I get the following error: "AttributeError
Exception Value:v'module' object has no attribute 'SupplierProfileAdmin'", the 2nd solution also throws an error. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @neurix The first was a typo. What's the error on the second one? It appears correct. Did you try adjusting the base class? See my edit.

Comment: Thank you for your help! with the changes from your post, I get new error "instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used". I have tried the "filter_horizontal" earlier, but it also did not work. Would be the better solution. Do you have a thought on the new error? How can I assign a primary key?

Comment: Thank you for all your explanations. All models have an id field and I migrated the tables with south (i checked the sql database). Your 2nd idea looks much more clean and straight-forward, but for some reason, it won't show up. I notice that the field name of horizontal_filter has no influence; if I enter an random name, I do not get an error msg. Do you know why that is the case? I have update the simplified code in the original question.

Comment: @neurix Also, there was another typo in my answer -- I left the `t` out of `horizontal`. Make sure you didn't just copy / paste my error.